# PHP Class Inheritance and Recursion

Tags: php, inheritance, recursion

The PHP manual for keyword [extends](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) says:

> Classes must be defined before they are used!

This code executes without error:

```
class A extends B {}
class B {}
new A();
```

But this code returns a fatal error - *Class ‘B’ not found in…*

```
class A extends B {}
class B extends A {}
new A();
```

I had assumed a mutual extension (second snippet) would go into recursion by trying to create A, then B, then A, etc.

But, obviously, by the time it tries to create class B, it realizes that A cannot be extended.

Does anyone know the underlying reason for this behavior? Does PHP keep a record of the classes that it attempts to create and know not to try a second time?

---

**Update:**

While this snippets works:

```
class A extends B {}
class B {}
new A();
```

This one does not:

```
class A extends B {} 
class B extends C {}
class C {}
new A();
```

So, it seems as @Mike pointed out, you must declare the parent class before extending it. (Although PHP is apparently forgiving in the case of a single child class.) That's why mutual recursion throws the fatal **Class 'B' not found** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes, a class with a certain *name* (ignoring namespaces) can only be defined once during script execution. You are essentially trying to define classes multiple (infinite) times.

Is there a reason you would want to do this? It seems pretty illogical to me. Unless you intended to write constructors to prevent it, all I can see is that you're trying to make an  infinite loop of extension ... what's the point? Curiosity? Don't you remember what happened to the cat?

**Edit**: To quote the PHP manual, "Classes must be defined before they are used! If you want the class Named_Cart to extend the class Cart, you will have to define the class Cart first ... the order in which the classes are defined is important." Class B was not found because it had not been declared yet before it was specified as a parent class or A. Reverse the order of your definitions and you're in the same boat because it's recursive.

Comment: Yes, complete curiosity. Are you saying that class A is considered defined even before PHP can find class B? If not, shouldn't PHP keep on trying to define it in a loop?

Comment: To quote the PHP manual, "Classes must be defined before they are used! If you want the class Named_Cart to extend the class Cart, you will have to define the class Cart first... To make it short: the order in which the classes are defined is important." That explains Class B not found. Because it's trying to extend B in before it's defined. Reverse the order of your definitions and you're in the same boat because it's recursive. This should probably be the answer, so I'm updating my answer.

Comment: The question is why throw a fatal error and why not php go into a loop on defining classes?

Comment: Because it can't extend B because it's not defined. Fatal error.

Comment: @Mike - I believe you have the right answer, although PHP is not consistent about this. This will work: `class A extends B {} class B {} new A();` but this will not: `class A extends B {} class B extends C {} class C {} new A();` So, the answer is that the class you're extending from _should_ be declared before the extension, and in this case it is impossible.

Comment: Weird... yeah you're right. I guess the first example you noted `class A extends B {} class B {} new A();` shouldn't work according to the manual because class B hasn't been declared yet.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet would always look for the definition of `class A` and not the definition of `class B`.

This is how php may look at the second snippet during runtime:

```
class A extends B {}
class B extends A {}
new A();
```

1. Define class A but I need to find the definition of class B first before defining class A.
2. I have found class B but I need to find the definition of class A first before defining class B.
3. Repeat 1.

In effect, PHP the does not find definition of class B because it ends up looking for the definition of class A.

Comment: Right, but my question is why PHP doesn't go into a loop (as you suggest in #3). Instead, it just throws a fatal error. I mean, it is logical, but what are the underpinnings of this behavior?

Comment: It is just how PHP does, just like in other OOP languages. The concept of inheritance should have a consistent hierarchy. But in this case, the hierarchy is endless. If you try this hierarchy of classes in other programming languages, it will throw an fatal error or exception. In short, the snippet violates the rule of inheritance and php stands on that rule. To quote from php manual: "An extended class is always dependent on a single base class". In the snippet, there is no base class.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your php version, it also does matter. I have tested it with php version 5.3.8, it works.

Comment: I've tested this on 5.3.8 as well and it doesn't work. It _shouldn't_ work - my question is what is the underlying reason for PHP throwing the fatal error of _class 'B' not found_ instead of infinite looping.